# Reduce cyclomatic complexity of my python code

Tags: python, fastapi

I have used Amazon Codeguru to analyze my code . It recommends me to reduce cyclomatic complexity. Here is an example of my code.

```py
from typing import Optional
    
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(...)
    description: Optional[str] 
    price: Optional[str] 
    tax: Optional[str] 
    specification: Optional[str]
    remarks: Optional[str]

#get_database_value gets data from database


@app.put("/items")
async def insert_item(item: Item):
    if item.description is None:
        item.description = get_database_value['item.description']
    if item.price is None:
        item.price = get_database_value['item.price']
    if item.tax is None:
        item.tax = get_database_value['item.tax']
    if item.remarks is None:
        item.remarks= get_database_value['item.remarks']
    if item.specification is None:
        item.specification =get_database_value['item.specification']
    results = {"item": item}
    return results
```

How to reduce cyclomatic complexity due to `if...else` condition ?

Comment: I'm no expert with Pydantic, but I think you can set default values on you model, if it does not bring issues to other Item related logic you could have?

Comment: This isn't a great match for stackoverflow; you'd be better off asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Pydantic can do all of this automagically for you; the `val` inside your `write_value` funciton is never used, you assign `item.remarks` when you probably meant `specification` (.. a good example of why it's far better to use Pydantic's support for this) and you assign an unnecessary variable at the end; start fixing those issues at least.

Comment: @MatsLindh For clearer I have edited write_value as get_database_value . If user did not provide data , it should get that data from database

Comment: What is the point of bindly following suggestions of a tool? Or worse, asking the internet community to spend time following instructions of the tool? True, this code is suspicious also to my human eyes, but not because of the number of "ifs" but because I don't get why they are needed. Either way, code style questions are opinion based and off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather let Pydantic do that for you by defining default values, and since you need to assign a default value, not `None` (as shown in your code), you don't need to use the `Optional` keyword (the parameters will still be "optional", when defining default values).

### Example

```py
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(...)
    description: str = get_database_value['item.description']
    price: str = get_database_value['item.price']
    tax: str = get_database_value['item.tax']
    specification: str = get_database_value['item.specification']
    remarks: str = get_database_value['item.remarks']
```

If you would also like to prevent users from sending empty strings (e.g., `tax=""`), you could define a minimum length for the parameters. Have a look [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customisation) on how you can customise a Pydantic Field.

```py
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(...)
    description: str = Field(default=get_database_value['item.description'], min_length=1)
    price: str = Field(default=get_database_value['item.price'], min_length=1)
    tax: str = Field(default=get_database_value['item.tax'], min_length=1)
    specification: str = Field(default=get_database_value['item.specification'], min_length=1)
    remarks: str = Field(default=get_database_value['item.remarks'], min_length=1)
```

Your endpoint should then look like this:

```
@app.put("/items")
async def insert_item(item: Item):
    return {"item": item}
```

Comment: If user inputs value then this doesn't work. I need to show user input data if user provides data else data from database

Comment: It works but in pydantic model , I dont want to assign get_database_value in basemodel. My project flow is importing pydantic model in another file (say crud.py), I perform all action like getting database value and finally importing them in api file.